# Zoom in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, zooming, uipageviewcontroller

I have used UIPageViewcontroller in StoryBoard & i want to pinch zoom for the UIPageViewController.

Here is my implementation. Please help me out. I'm a newbie to iOS.

TypeA1ViewController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface TypeA1ViewController : UIPageViewController<UIPageViewControllerDataSource>

    @end
```

TypeA1ViewController.m

```
    #import "TypeA1ViewController.h"

    #import "TypesPhotoViewController.h"

    @interface TypeA1ViewController ()
    {
        NSArray* _imagesNames;
    }

    @end

    @implementation TypeA1ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        _imagesNames = @[@"Type-A1.jpg",@"SpecsCDE.png" ];
        self.dataSource = self;
        [self setViewControllers:@[[[TypesPhotoViewController alloc] initWithImageNAme:_imagesNames[0] atIndex:0]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:NULL];

    }

    - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(TypesPhotoViewController *)viewController
    {
        if( viewController.pageIndex ==[_imagesNames count]-1)
        {
            return nil;
        }
        else
        {
            return [[TypesPhotoViewController alloc] initWithImageNAme:_imagesNames[viewController.pageIndex+1] atIndex:viewController.pageIndex+1] ;
        }
    }

    -(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(TypesPhotoViewController *)viewController
    {
        if (viewController.pageIndex==0) {
            return nil;
        } else {
            return [[TypesPhotoViewController alloc] initWithImageNAme:_imagesNames[viewController.pageIndex-1] atIndex:viewController.pageIndex-1];
        }
    }

    @end
```